# Regarding INA 212(a)(7)(A)(i)(I)

Tags: customs-and-immigration

My girlfriend is a Canadian Citizen.  In January 2014 she was issued the above form, a voluntary withdrawal of application for admission.  Since then, any time she attempts to enter the U.S. she is pulled into secondary questioning, which can be a very intimidating and upsetting experience.  We have looked around, and seen some things that say this is permanent, and others that say it can be for 5, 10, 15 years, etc.  Is there a non-legalese explanation of what this form means somewhere, how long it lasts, and if necessary how to get it removed (or apply for it to be waived?) or if it is a permanent mark?

Comment: @phoog The form she has says "Withdrawal of Application for Admission / Consular Notification", I don't have a copy of it myself but I can probably get one from her if necessary.  She was initially trying to reenter to get some of her belongings from a previous marriage.

Comment: Had she had a green card?  Did she relinquish it then?

Comment: If this is a matter of needing to see the form itself, or if I have worded something poorly, I'm happy to provide further information/clarify

Comment: @TimLymington she withdrew her application to enter the US on a single occasion, not the same as "waiving a right to enter the US" (which most aliens don't have anyway). It seems that she was found to have immigrant intent, since the cited section of code is that for immigrants who lack an immigrant visa.  This can apparently happen to people who are found to have relinquished their permanent resident status, though as far as I'm aware they're usually admitted as nonimmigrants in such cases.  Michael: it may help if you can post an image of the form with identifying information blacked out.

Comment: I found the [relevant section of INA 212 = 8 USC 1182(a)(7)(A)(i)(I))](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_7_A_i_I) but the details aren't clear to me. Have you tried asking the US consulate in Canada for advice?

Comment: @phoog I can see if I can get a copy of it with the information redacted, thanks for your help

Comment: @krubo We haven't contacted anyone yet as we weren't sure what the proper procedure was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that she was denied entry that time for failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent. INA 212(a)(7)(A)(i)(I) says you are inadmissible as an immigrant if you don't have an immigrant visa. The logic of why immigrant intent leads to this inadmissibility is kind of indirect -- she was seeking entry as a nonimmigrant (a visitor), but since she failed to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, the law "presumes" she was an immigrant, and then says she couldn't enter because she didn't have an immigrant visa (which she obviously wouldn't have since she was seeking to enter as a nonimmigrant).

Failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent is the most common, generic reason officers use to deny visas or deny entry to nonimmigrants when there's anything they don't like about the person's case or situation. Whether someone convinces the officer that they have no immigrant intent or not is primarily subjective, and any negative factor in the person's case can make it harder for the officer to be convinced. For people applying for visas, they usually get denied at the visa stage under INA 214(b). But Canadians don't need visas to visit the US, so they can only be denied at entry, and when denied at entry for immigrant intent, they give the code INA 212(a)(7)(A)(i)(I).

Inadmissibility on INA 212(a)(7)(A)(i)(I) applies only to a particular entry. Unlike some other inadmissibilities that say one is inadmissible for a period of time or permanently, i.e. you have a "ban", this inadmissibility just means you were inadmissible that particular time. It doesn't mean you will be inadmissible the next time. However, there *is* a ban that might be triggered when someone is denied entry for this reason, INA 212(a)(9)(A)(i).

When someone is denied entry to the US, one of two things happen: 1) they are allowed to withdraw their application for admission and voluntarily deport, or 2) they are removed. (Though if she was entering at a preclearance facility like a Canadian airport, I don't think she can be removed since she is not in the US, so I believe #2 above doesn't apply.) Whether to allow someone to withdraw their application and voluntarily depart is at the discretion of the officer -- the officer doesn't have to allow it even if the person offers to voluntarily depart. If the person is "removed", that automatically triggers a 5-year ban under INA 212(a)(9)(A)(i). If they are allowed to withdraw their application and voluntarily depart, they do not trigger a ban. In your girlfriend's case, we know she was allowed to withdraw her application and voluntarily depart, so she does not have this ban.

Just because she has no ban doesn't mean they will let her into the US. They could still deny her entry for immigrant intent, or they could let her in for a shorter time, or otherwise subject her to extra scrutiny. The record of her denied entry, and whatever notes they put into the system that time, is seen when she later seeks to enter and is probably causing her to be placed in secondary. There is not much she can really do about this. This is not a ban; so there is no "waiver" to file. It is just individual immigration officers (probably different officers each time), deciding to subject her to extra checks based on her history, which is in their discretion. If she immigrates to the US, then she would probably no longer be scrutinized for this reason.